# Hosting Linux: Is there any way to run multiple website applications?

Tags: webserver

I'm working on some ASP.NET Core application, and i need to run a few web project on a Linux webserver. How can i run multiple instance on a single Linux Server? By now i have always used a windows server with IIS and, thanks to the application pool, i was able to run multiple instance. But now i can't find anywhere a way to do something similar on Linux. Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure the applications use different ports and you should be all set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're asking for multiple instances, are you referring to multiple websites?  If so what you're looking for is called Virtual Host.  This can definitely be setup within Apache.

See the following link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Depending on your flavor of Linux that you wish to use, the instructions vary slightly.  But I'm biased and love Ubuntu.